# Grab Bitmap-Image (Winforms) and convert to WPF-Image fails

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, bitmap, dispatcher

I grab an image from a external camera. The winforms application works so far. Now I need to transfer it to WPF. Therefore I converted the bitmap-image to WPF like this:

```
    GrabHandler frameCallbackDelegate;
    void frameCallBack(IntPtr lpUserData, ref VCECLB_FrameInfoEx frameInfo)
    {
        if (frameInfo.dma_status != 0) return;

        // fill image
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        BitmapData bmdata = image.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, image.PixelFormat);

        UInt32 outputBitDepth;
        IntPtr stride = new IntPtr(bmdata.Stride);

        VCECLB_Error err = NativeFunctions.VCECLB_UnpackRawPixelsEx(ref pRawPixelInfo, frameInfo.lpRawBuffer, bmdata.Scan0, ref stride, VCECLB_Output_Format.VCECLB_EX_FMT_TopDown | VCECLB_Output_Format.VCECLB_EX_FMT_3Channel, out outputBitDepth);

        image.UnlockBits(bmdata);



        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            // Convert bitmap to WPF-Image
            var bmp = new Bitmap(image);
            var hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();

            ImageSource wpfBitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                        hBitmap,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        Int32Rect.Empty,
                        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            image_LowLight.Source = wpfBitmap;

            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            image.Dispose();
            }));
        GC.Collect();


    }


    private void StartGrab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        start_button.IsEnabled = true;
        stop_button.IsEnabled = false;

        frameCallbackDelegate = new GrabHandler(frameCallBack);
        m_ImageAquisition.StartGrab(frameCallbackDelegate);
    }
```

When I enter for the first time the **frameCallBack** from the **StartGrab**, the **image.Width** and **image.Height** have a valid value (not 0) and it seems correct. When the **frameCallBack** is entered for the second time all image-data (width and height) are 0 and therefore rect gives an error.

Is there something wrong in the way I am using the Dispatcher.Invoke to get a valid bitmap-image?

Thanks!

Comment: The Dispatcher will invoke your Action() at some later time. Probably lprawBuffer is not valid at this time. I think you should copy your imagedate in some local buffer before you register Action() with the Dispatcher.

Comment: ok but how would you do that? Is it also possible to call the **frameCallBack** lets say every second?

Comment: Have you thought of using `<WindowsFormsHost><wf:Panel x:Name="videoPanel"/></WindowsFormsHost>` to have WinForms in your WPF app without all this converting ? BTW wf = `xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"`. HTH

Comment: @XAMlMAX You mean I can use the winform code as it is without converting it in a WPF-application? Sounds very interesting but I am struggling a bit on how to use it. Could give an example on how to do that?

Comment: yes, create control that utilizes usage of the camera and build it as a library. then just import the library into your WPF project and then use it in xaml. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Is it possible to build such library directly from my existing windowsform project? Or do I need to start with a new project first to create such library?

Comment: I made a sample project with a UserControl for adding to the WPF-project. The problem is that this UserControl is still greyed-out in the WPF-solution so I can not drag it to the design-window. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using volatile data in an Action() which gets executed some time later by the Dispatcher.

Refactor your code like this:

```
   GrabHandler frameCallbackDelegate;
    void frameCallBack(IntPtr lpUserData, ref VCECLB_FrameInfoEx frameInfo)
    {
        if (frameInfo.dma_status != 0) return;

        // fill image
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        BitmapData bmdata = image.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, image.PixelFormat);

        UInt32 outputBitDepth;
        IntPtr stride = new IntPtr(bmdata.Stride);

        VCECLB_Error err = NativeFunctions.VCECLB_UnpackRawPixelsEx(ref pRawPixelInfo, frameInfo.lpRawBuffer, bmdata.Scan0, ref stride, VCECLB_Output_Format.VCECLB_EX_FMT_TopDown | VCECLB_Output_Format.VCECLB_EX_FMT_3Channel, out outputBitDepth);

        image.UnlockBits(bmdata);

        // Convert bitmap to WPF-Image
        var bmp = new Bitmap(image);
        var hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();

        ImageSource wpfBitmap =
            System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                        hBitmap,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        Int32Rect.Empty,
                        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        image.Dispose();

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            image_LowLight.Source = wpfBitmap;
        }));
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: good point! When the debugger runs until the end of **GC.Collect();** the **bmdata** has data and the **image.width** and **image.height** are also ok. What I see is that those **bmdata** are not transfered to the source **image_LowLight** and therefore the bitmap is not shown on the GUI. It looks like there is a problem with the conversion of the bitmap.